# Python Jaro–Winkler similarity loop optimization

Tags: python, optimization, multiprocessing

I have a loop - 5kk times do 5k comparisons. Is there a way to do it faster (like multiprocessing/paralleling) or any other way?

My code:

```
from pyjarowinkler import distance

for i in lst:
    for j in list_unis:
        distance.get_jaro_distance(str(i), str(j), winkler=True, scaling=0.1)

lst -       list of 5kk entries
list_unis - list of 5k entries
```

Comment: That´s way too many operations, what are you trying to do?

Comment: want to measure jaro_winkler distance between every element from list called 'lst' and elements from list called 'list_unis'.

Comment: But what for? If you only want top k or just closest, you don´t really need to calculate all

Comment: Actually i want to find a maximum value of distance of every i among all j's. In other words: find max(j) for every i.
So final result would be:
    value_of_i   value_of_j     distance
   'Stanford'    'Stanforddd'   0.96

Comment: But in order to find the top match(-es), I need to evaluate all distances, don't you think so?

Comment: There are ways to skip some comparisons from list_unis by using upper bounds, like the distance between the 2 strings, but not sure if it would be worth for only 5k, don´t think time would reduce more than half. If you want to go that approach, read the paper called On the Efficient Execution of Bounded
Jaro-Winkler Distances. Paralleling is simpler and will and faster result depending on how many logical units you have on your pc, but keep in mind that it will still take a long time and python is slow for these things. Even a single for iterating lst will take some time

Comment: thanks @juvian.  do you have any other ideas how to improve performance? I will try what you've posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185191/discussion-between-bc1554-and-juvian).